# Tab page will not receive focus when using the tab button on the keyboard

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a tab control with two tab pages. I have set the tab index correctly on the tab control using visual studio tab order function. The tab stop property is set to true on the control. However, when I try to use the tab key on the keyboard, the second tab page will not gain focus. My question is how can I make the second tab page appear when you use the tab button on the keyboard?

Comment: `Ctrl + Tab` will switch tabs.

Comment: It does not do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround maybe you can refer to.

You can try to override `ProcessCmdKey` and call `ActiveControl.TabIndex` to check whether the current focus is on `TabControl`.

If the currently active control is `TabControl`, simulate "Key Right pressed" to switch TabPage.

```
// tabpage count
int count = 1;

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    bool baseResult = base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

    if (keyData == Keys.Tab && ActiveControl.TabIndex == tabControl1.TabIndex)
    {
        if (count < tabControl1.TabPages.Count)
        {
            // simulate key right pressed
            SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}");
            count++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // reset count and selected tabpage
            count = 1;
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    return baseResult;
}
```

Test result:

[image]